# Enable keyboard shortcut for escaping Monaco suggestions widget only when it is visible

Tags: monaco-editor

I've added a shortcut to escape the Monaco suggestions widget with the space bar, which caused the space bar not to work anymore as a space bar.
I'm thinking that ideally, I would just have to add a conditional that would enable the shortcut only when the Monaco suggestions widget is visible, is it something that is feasible?

Here is my code, so far:

```
const hideSuggestions = editor.createContextKey('hideSuggestions', true)

editor.addCommand(
  monaco.KeyCode.Space, function () {editor.trigger('', 'hideSuggestWidget', null) }, 'hideSuggestions' )
```

I'm only missing some way of changing `hideSuggestions` from true to false whether the Monaco suggestions widget is triggered or not.

Comment: Why's escape not good for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `addCommand` use the more advanced `addAction` method, which allows to specify preconditions:

```js
        const blockContext = "editorTextFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible && !renameInputVisible && !inSnippetMode " +
            "&& !quickFixWidgetVisible";

            editor.addAction({
                id: "executeCurrent",
                label: "Execute Block",
                keybindings: [KeyMod.Shift | KeyCode.Enter],
                contextMenuGroupId: "2_execution",
                precondition: blockContext,
                run: () => { return this.executeCurrentContext(false, false); },
            });
```

I use this for running an action when the user presses <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.